# IBM Lift CLI cannot connect to source database

Tags: db2

I am having an issue connecting to the source database when attempting to extract a table.

**Here is the error message**:

> LIFT-4000: Failed acquiring connection for the database SKILLST after
>   multiple retries. Ensure that host, port and credentials are correct.
>
> Netezza: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Connection reset)

Also, when trying to migrate DDL from a source to a target database db2, I receive this message:

> Generating DDL statement(s) for specified database objects...
>   LIFT-4030: No object found in schema TADB2 matching with specified
>   condition.

We have verified the host port, username, password, and all conditions are correct. Even still, we are receiving the LIFT-4030 error above.

Our version of db2 is:

> "DB2 v11.1.3.3"

Comment: Can you post your lift cli statement? What is your source DBMS?

Comment: **Lift Migrate Statement:** _lift ddl --migrate --source-schema <myschema> --source-database <mydatabasename> --source-object <table1> --source-user <username> --source-password <password> --source-host <host ip> --source-database-port <port number> --source-database-type db2 --target-schema <target schema> --target-object <table1[same table]> --object-type all --target-user <username> --target-password <password> --target-host <targethostaddress>_ @PaulVernon

Comment: And this is our **Extract Statement:** _lift extract --source-schema <srcSchema> --source-table <srcTable> --source-database <srcDbName> --source-user <srcUser> --source-password <srcPass> --source-host <srcDbHost> --source-database-port <portnumber>_ @PaulVernon

Comment: I guess I was hoping you might show the real table, schema names. Does the case of your `<sctTable>` name match the table name in your source system? What version of lift are you using. What is the target database. Is SKILLST your source or target database. Are the two issues related?   In short, your explanation of your issue could be better..    you might want to create a new question (or two if you have two different issues) and explain the issue a little better

Comment: Looking at the command reference, I suggest you specify the `--source-database-type db2` on your `lift extract` command. Your first error message suggests that lift is assuming your source is Netezza, but you imply that your source is Db2